# AngularJS: Inject Restangular and use $location in factory

Tags: angularjs

I have the following factory.  I use it to store lists of tabs in various parts of my program.

```
myApp.factory('RootService', function($location) {
    var tabList = [ ... ];
    var loginTabList = [ ... ];

    return {
        setTabList: function(data) {
            tabList = data;
        },
        getTabList: function(data) {
            if ($location.path() !== '/login') { return tabList; }
            else {
                if (data === 0) { return loginTabList; }
                else { return tabList; }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

I wanted to move the initialization of these lists to my Java layer so that I can have them populate from an Oracle database.  I have the back-end sorted out, but when I attempt to inject Restangular into the factory so that I can use it, the factory prevents AngularJS from functioning at all.  With minor changes, I can get AngularJS to work again with one:

```
myApp.factory('RootService', function($location) { ... });
```

Or the other:

```
myApp.factory('RootService', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) { ... }]);
```

declarations but not both.  Am I declaring the factory incorrectly?  How can I use both Restangular and $location together?

Comment: can you post the code that use you use with $location and Restangular
such as ```myApp.factory('RootService', ['Restangular','$location', function(Restangular,$location) { ... }]);```

Comment: @DavidChase I tried the declaration in your comment and AngularJS did not break.  If you leave something similar as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer if my Restangular tests work, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
myApp.factory('RootService', ['Restangular','$location', 
function(Restangular, $location) { 
... 
}]);
```

It is possible that you didnt use the inline annotation for both `$location` and `Restangular`

more on that [**here**](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-annotation)

Answer (score 1):

it should be okay to define your factory like this

```
app.factory('RootService', ['Restangular','$location', function(Restangular,$location) {
  ...
}]);
```

here is a working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZAvojovfci0NfHpXqeB?p=preview) example...